# Pass on Argument in #selector Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a method:

```
func followUnfollow(followIcon: UIImageView, channelId: String) {
    let followUnfollow = followIcon
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.followIconTapped(_:)))
    followUnfollow.userInteractionEnabled = true
    followUnfollow.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

And also I have a method:

```
func followIconTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    ...
}
```

And it's work all right. But I need to pass on `channelId` to `followIconTapped()` method.

I try this:

```
func followUnfollow(followIcon: UIImageView, channelId: String) {
    ...
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.followIconTapped(_:channelId)))
    ...
}
```

and then I try catch it:

```
func followIconTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, channelId: String) {
    ...
}
```

xCode say that `channelId` will never used. Why?
 When I build project I haven't any issue. But app is crash if I tap on **followIcon**.

Please, can you give me advice how to pass on `channelId` to `followIconTapped()`

Comment: Where does the `channelId` come from? `func followIconTapped` is called by `UITapGestureRecognizer` and it has no way of knowing about it. It seems that you should save `channelId` in a class property when it is chosen, and the use it in this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

creating a generic `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead use this:

```
class CustomTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var channelId: String?
}
```

also use this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gestureRecognizer = CustomTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:))
    gestureRecognizer.channelId = "Your string"
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func tapped(gestureRecognizer: CustomTapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let channelId = gestureRecognizer.channelId {
        //print
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a typo in your code sample - `if let channelId = gestureRecognizer.headline {` -> this should rather be `if let channelId = gestureRecognizer.channelId {`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a tag for `tapGestureRecognizer` and define `channelId` depend on tag.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass extra arguments to your method when you are using `Selector`. UITapGestureRecognizer can handle methods with signatures:

- `private dynamic func handleTap() { ... }`
- `private dynamic func handleTapOn(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) { ... }`

Selectors in swift aren't validate in other way then check syntactics. Thats why there is no error connected with method signature you pass to action method.

If you like use `channelId` in your `handleTap` method you have to keep your variable in some place. You can create property in your class and store there your variable to use in `handleTap` method.

```
class YourClass: BaseClass {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var channellId: String? = nil 

    // MARK: - API

    func followUnfollow(followIcon: UIImageView, channelId: String) {
        self.channelId = channelId
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapOn(_:)))
    }

    // MARK: - Callbacks

    private dynamic func handleTapOn(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let channelId = self.channelId {
            // Do sth
        }
    }

}
```